# to avoid null characters in powershell

Tags: powershell, null, switch-statement, do-while

```
$q = 0
do {
    $a = write-input "enter value"

    switch ($a) {
        1.{ some option }
        2.{}
        default {}
    }
} while ($a -gt $q)
```

In the above code, if we give `$a=$null` value then switch terminates from `while` loop. Please help me out to skip null checking and to continue in the loop.

Comment: `$a -gt $q` -> `$a -eq $null -or $a -gt $q`

Comment: if $a -eq $null is used i will terminate out of the loop ...loop shouldn't terminate for null values read

Comment: Then the value of `$a` is not `$null` in the first place. Is it an empty string? If so `-not $a -or $a -gt $q` might work. What exactly does `write-input` do/return? There is no standard cmdlet of that name.

Comment: its read-host and not write-input. Your supplying values to $a which executes switch cases. So when you give blank space as input it should return as invalid input instead of exiting out of the do while loop

Comment: Trim the input: `$a.Trim() -ne '' -or [int]$a -gt $q`

Answer (score 0):

As Ansgar Wiechers points out in the comments, the comparison `$null -gt 0` is `False`. This terminates your `While` loop. You could update your `while` statement to `while ($a -eq $null -or $a -gt $q)`

Another alternative would be use a recursive function,

```
function Example-Function {
    switch (Read-Host "Enter Value") {
        1 { "Option 1"; Example-Function }
        2 { "Option 2"; Example-Function }
        default { "Invalid Option, Exiting" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice use of recursion in PS. First time I've seen a valid use-case for it. OP might want to expand on the options being listed e.g. `"Options:`r`nOpt 1: thing"`prior to the switch